# How do you combine two char_t* strings?

Tags: c++, winapi, concatenation, wchar

What I am trying to do is get a list of processes in an edit child window. I originally was gonna use a series of buttons with a scroll bar but I don't know how to do that (if you have a solution for that) and found no resources how to.

I tried wchar.h functions, and type casting.

```
HWND listProc = CreateWindow(L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
            0, 0, 100, 300, process, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        LPWSTR procList = L'';
        Process32First(procSnap, &procEntry);
        while (Process32Next(procSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            wcsncat(procList, procEntry.szExeFile, MAX_PATH);
            wcsncat(procList, L"\n", 1);
        }
        SetWindowText(listProc, procList);
        CloseHandle(procSnap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As @jkb metioned, use`std::wstring`;
2. use `std::stringstream`.(or any other stream class)

In addition, there are other problems in your sample. If you don't want your output text to be one line and hard to read, you need to add the Exstyle of `ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL` to your edit control, and **use `"\r\n"` to connect strings to Wrap text.**

1). Sample:

```
   HWND listProc = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL| ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
       0, 0, 100, 300, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

   HANDLE procSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

   std::wstring procList;
   PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
   procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
   Process32First(procSnap, &procEntry);
   procList += procEntry.szExeFile;
   procList += L"\r\n";
   while (Process32Next(procSnap, &procEntry))
   {
       procList += procEntry.szExeFile;
       procList += L"\r\n";
   }
   SetWindowText(listProc, procList.c_str());
   CloseHandle(procSnap);
```

2). Sample:

```
   HWND listProc = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Edit", L"", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL| ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,
       0, 0, 100, 300, process, NULL, NULL, NULL);

   HANDLE procSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

   std::wstringstream procList;
   PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
   procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
   Process32First(procSnap, &procEntry);
   procList += procEntry.szExeFile;
   procList += L"\r\n";
   while (Process32Next(procSnap, &procEntry))
   {
       procList << procEntry.szExeFile;
       procList << L"\r\n";
   }

   SetWindowText(listProc, procList.str().c_str());
   CloseHandle(procSnap);
```

Comment: Thank you. You managed to answer my question and then read my mind with the new one I had. Not sure which to mark with acceptance so I chose a random one.

Comment: Also, you'll want to change your `while` loop into a `do/while` or you'll lose the info about the first process.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code will not compile:

```cpp
LPWSTR procList = L'';
```

you cannot initialize a pointer with a single wide character.

Second, assuming you intended to initialize `procList` to an empty string, your calls to `wcsncat` will result in undefined behavior since that function expects the destination to point to enough space to perform the concatenation. It will not allocate additional memory.

I recommend you not use C-style strings at all, and use `std::wstring` instead. You can concatenate additional strings with the `+=` operator, and additional memory *will* be allocated. You can pass the string contents to `SetWindowText` by using the `c_str()` function.